# OAuth Consent Screen - Google hasn't verified this app

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I faced with the following problem:
OAuth screen of my application has been verified and in console.cloud.google.com has the Verification Status "Verified", but one of the users gets the OAuth screen "Google hasn't verified this app".

User uses MacOS and Unverified OAuth screen gets in Safari and in Chrome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

App is verified but when i send the request with the scope which is not added to the scopes.